# Strict hostname resolution configured but no hostname was set

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to start a Java application which apparently enforces hostname resolution:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Strict hostname resolution configured but no hostname was set
```

I've tried applying an hostname:

```
sudo hostname fedora
```

but it didn't help. On this machine, my /etc/hosts looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1 fedora
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Besides that, I didn't configure anything else, it's a freshly installed Fedora 35 Desktop distribution.

here's the output of hostnamectl:

```
hostnamectl
 Static hostname: fedora
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         Boot ID: 5fa811cbfaf74fc3947656db997c1110
Operating System: Fedora Linux 35 (Workstation Edition)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:35
          Kernel: Linux 5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: ThinkPad P1 Gen 3
```

Any help?

Edit: The Java application is starting is [Keycloak 17](https://www.keycloak.org/)

Comment: Can you update your question by adding the output of `hostnamectl` ?

Comment: Thanks! I've just updated it.

Comment: Would you please share what Java application this is?

Comment: @Carla so your application probably wants to see a FQDN and `fedora` does not provide that. So you can run something like `hostnamectl set-hostname fedora.local --static`. You can look into more options using `hostnamectl --help`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with Keycloak 17, strict host resolution is required in production mode. You can either provide the actual host name with the `--hostname` parameter or disable strict host resolution with the startup parameter:
`–-hostname-strict=false`

Source: [getting started with keycloak 17](http://www.mastertheboss.com/keycloak/getting-started-with-keycloak-17)